# numpy .dot using lists and arrays, whats the difference

Tags: python, numpy

When multiplication of two similar matrices `1*2` like `[1,2]`, `[3,5]` is carried out using `numpy.dot`, it gives a result, when in fact it should be giving a shape and dimension error like while multiplying two similar arrays. What is going on under the hood?

```
a=[1,2]
b=[6,3]
result=[np.dot(b, a)]
print(result)
```

> O/P= 12

But,

```
a=[[1,2]]
b=[[6,3]]
result=[np.dot(b, a)]
print(result)
```

Error:

> O/P= ValueError: shapes (1,2) and (1,2) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 1
>   (dim 0)

Comment: To be picky, both of your inputs are lists.  When converted to `ndarray`, which `dot` will do, they are 1d and 2d respectively.

Answer (score 2):

As per the documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html),

- If both `a` and `b` are `1-D` arrays, it is inner product of vectors (without complex conjugation).
- If both `a` and `b` are `2-D` arrays, it is matrix multiplication, but using `matmul` or `a @ b` is preferred.

**Case 1**: `a` and `b` are `1-D` arrays, so result is `1*6+2*3=12`.

**Case 2**: `a` and `b` are `2-D` arrays, so we will do matrix product of these two. It raises `ValueError` since the last dimension of `a` is not the same size as the second-to-last dimension of `b`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to [Anubhav Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5810950/anubhav-singh)'s correct answer, note that a matrix product of a row vector with a column vector returns a 1-by-1 matrix whose sole entry *is* the dot product of the two vectors, so in this case,

```py
In [32]: a = np.array([[1,2]])

In [33]: b = np.array([[6,3]])

In [34]: a @ b.T
Out[34]: array([[12]])

In [35]: np.dot(a, b.T)
Out[35]: array([[12]])

In [36]: np.dot(a[0], b[0])
Out[36]: 12
```

This is why `np.dot` behaves the way it does.